# QT - How can I make this array global for my GUI?

Tags: c++, qt

```
QSpinBox* spinright[size] = {ui->norm_spinBox_2,
                             ui->norm_spinBox_3,
                          ui->norm_spinBox_4,
                          ui->norm_spinBox_5,
                          ui->norm_spinBox_6,
                          ui->norm_spinBox_7,
                          ui->norm_spinBox_8};
```

I'd like to be able to access this array in two spots in my program. However, if there is a better alternative for this solution I’m all ears. I tried to create a function that could be called for this program; however it started to get long and dragged out that it was becoming less worth it to go this route.

This is how I've set up the Hierarchy. My overall attempt is to make some buttons appear and disappear when a button is pressed. If it's possible to make the vertical layouts disappear then this would be a better way to go.

[image: Tree of boxes]

In the end I'll take whatever solution, that may be offered here.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have you tried signal/slot connections between buttons and related controls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void GuiTest::setLabelsVisible(int index, bool visible){
    QLabel* labels[norm_size] = {ui->norm_label_2,
                                 ui->norm_label_3,
                                 ui->norm_label_4,
                                 ui->norm_label_5,
                                 ui->norm_label_6,
                                 ui->norm_label_7,
                                 ui->norm_label_8};
    labels[index]->setVisible(visible);
}
```

the best way to do this, I found, would to go this direction. Instead of setting this list of objects as global just have separate functions that will manipulate the structure in some way.